# Is it mandatory to implement abstract methods in all subclasses?

Tags: oop

I've got some subclasses that implement a particular method, declared as abstract in their superclass. What if, in addition, I have one more subclass that should not implement that particular method?

That's the same question I have for fields. Is it common to have a subclass that simply ignore some fields of its superclass?

This not about any specific technology, just about good programming practice.

Comment: It totally depends on the use case.

Comment: There's a design anti pattern called "refused bequest" that describes this situation; google that. Basically, if you're seeing this, then it suggests there's a problem with your design.

Comment: Thanks, Ernest! That has totally put light on what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: You need not implement them, if your derived class is abstract, too. But all non-abstract derived classes have to implement them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably room for discussion of the semantics of "mandatory" in various technologies, but in general, yes it is mandatory.  One of the fundamental rules of OO is that anywhere the superclass is valid, the subclass must also be valid at least as a type.  If you were to somehow remove a method or field (or fail to supply it), then you violate that rule as any context using that method/field in the super is no longer valid.  It could be argued that if you don't fill in those abstract items then you don't have a sub-class.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement all abstract methods inside the subclass unless your subclass is an abstract class. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

(C#)
Yes you have to implement the all methods of parent or base class in subclass, unless subclass is not an abstract class (mentioned in above comment).

however, if you have **virtual** method in base or parent class, you have option either implement(using override keyword) or not, it upto you.